# suppress Paramiko stderr output

Tags: python, logging, paramiko

I am using paramiko as part of a python script.  In this script, I am also using python's logging module to log to both a logfile and stderr.  Only what I specify via logger.debug, logger.info, etc should display in the console.  Unfortunately, when I make calls to paramiko as follows:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=user, key_filename=keyfile)
```

The following message outputs to stderr:

*CryptographyDeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.*

I have tried to suppress by altering paramiko's logging to CRITICAL like this:

```
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

As well as directing it to a file like this:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file('filename.log')
```

But neither works.

**Is there a way to make this stop showing up as console output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue that still exists with `paramiko==2.4.2` ; it's scheduled apparently [for the next 2.x release](http://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html), so likely for 2.5.

The problem they state is essentially, "older `paramiko`, newer `cryptography`"

In the meantime, you can try this to fix it:

```sh
pip uninstall cryptography ; pip install cryptography==$DESIRED_VERSION
```

Replace `$DESIRED_VERSION` with [the version you need](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#history). paramiko 2.4.2 was released in September 2018, the latest point release that looks compatible is cryptography 2.3.1. In my setup, it works.

This essentially means downgrading your cryptography package, so think twice before you do it.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the option to do that in this case, and ended up finding an alternative as I had not been able to resolve this.  But this answer is very good to know, thank you very much for letting me know about this!

Comment: Is it not even a possibility with `virtualenv`? in case it helps. yes, I had to hunt around for the answer, and this post kept on coming up, so thought I'd answer :-)

Comment: virtualenv is a great idea, i'm glad you posted it.  when i created this post i was not using any virtual environment or aware of that option.  I think it would be a good solution, i think it's a suggestion that i hope saves others some pain :)